# Why is the nsfw property is missing from a TextChannel from client.on("messageCreate")?

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

I'm using Typescript with Discord.js v14. I'm getting the error:

```
Property 'nsfw' does not exist on type 'DMChannel | PartialDMChannel | ...
```

Here is the code:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async msg => {
   if (msg.channel.nsfw) { // here is where the error takes place
      msg.reply("That's kinda nsfw man..");
   }
})
```

I tried manually type-casting `msg.channel` to a `BaseGuildTextChannel` but it was too unsafe for me.
Is there another way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The channel a message came from can be of many types, Typescript is telling you the `.nsfw` property is not found on every possible type as DM channels are missing this property. Add a type guard:

```js
// require/import ChannelType from discord.js

client.on("messageCreate", async msg => {
   if (msg.channel.type !== ChannelType.GuildText) return;

   if (msg.channel.nsfw) {
      msg.reply("That's kinda nsfw man..");
   }
})
```

Typescript will then know that any channel that passed the first statement will be a guild text channel.